# How to custom row when I create row has checkbox in ng2-smart-table?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ng2-smart-table

I want when I create new row, In Status columns is checkbox. In Image is Input text
[image: I want when I create new row, In Status columns is checkbox. In Image is Input text]

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve] of what you tried, you can [edit] the question and add it

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I can not provide you a full sample code right now but you should define a column for your checkbox. Provide a boolean value for that column. Don't forget to add
'type: custom'
It renders the Component you provide. I used a component named MyCheckboxComponent

```
<nb-checkbox [ngModel]="selected"></nb-checkbox>
```

nb-checkbox is in nebular library.

```
settings = {
  columns: {
   checkBox: {
     type: 'custom',
     filter: false,
     width: '10px',
     renderComponent: MyCheckboxComponent
   }
  }
 }
```